# Groupby() and mean() in pandas dataframe with returning more than two columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, mean

A super simple question, which I cannot find so far.

This is my dataframe

```
    id  Name    Lastname    Journal     Article   Score
0   1   John    Doo         Journal2    Article1    23
1   2   John    Doo         Journal1    Article2    12
2   3   Bill    Foo         Journal17   Article3    8
```

When I use

```
df.groupby('id', as_index=False)['Score'].mean()
```

it gives me

```
    id  Score
0   1   17.5
1   2   8.0
```

Expected output

```
   id   Name Lastname Score
0   1   Joe  Doe      17.5
1   2   Bill Foo      8.0
```

Comment: Your example is not completely consistent, so not sure, but `.groupby(  ).Score.transform('mean')`  might be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If same values per `id` in `Name` and `Lastname` columns add it to `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(['id','Name','Lastname'], as_index=False)['Score'].mean()
```

If possible different values per `id` is possible extract first/last values per groups:

```
df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'Score':'mean', 'Name':'first', 'Lastname':'first'})

df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'Score':'mean', 'Name':'last', 'Lastname':'last'})
```

Comment: thanks. what if name column contains NaNs. and gives me an error in the first solution. how would you update the code?

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker - I think if `NaNs` need second solution, because `first` return first non `NAN`s values per groups.

Comment: it gives me `ValueError: No axis named NAME for object type DataFrame` in my local dataframe

Comment: Nevermind, the second solution worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker - Can you check `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?